# RewriteRule that works with paginated pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to define a RewriteRule

Within the site I have pages like this:

```
index.php?pag=company&id=853
```

And I've defined this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9])/([0-9]+)$index.php?pag=company&id=$2 [NC, L]
```

Trying to get this result:

```
company/university-of-gloucestershire/1656
```

This rule works, however doesn't work for paginated pages, like:

```
index.php?pag=company&id=853&page=2
```

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?pag=company&id=$2&page=$4 [NC, L]
```

Trying to get to:

```
company/university-of-gloucestershire/1656/page/2
```

Can anyone point out what's wrong?

Comment: I restructured your question to make it easier to read.  I did not fix up the spaces you seemed to insert randomly between your rules and examples, since I don't know if that could be part of your problem.  Please use exact examples, it will make it easier for people to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks. This is real example of my problem.

Comment: Where is the 'page' pattern in your rewriteRule? Did you try something like Company # RewriteRule ^/(.*)/([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)$   ?

Comment: @RuiCosta, I'm pretty skeptical of that.  `index.php? pag = ...` is not a valid URL.  I imagine the actual URL is `index.php?pag=...` but I didn't want to refactor this for you unless that's actually the case.  Similarly, your rewrite rule has spaces which I'm skeptical are actually there (for instance, `[0-9] +` means something totally different than `[0-9]+`).  These spaces create ambiguity, making it more difficult to answer your question.

Comment: oh...i see your point, At my example that spaces doesn't exists...

Comment: Great.  Now, you say it "doesn't work".  What, exactly, doesn't work?  Do you get a 404?  Does the page not display the correct data?  Does your server start smoking and cursing your name?  You've got to give us more information than simply it "doesn't work".  A good starting point would be to check your server logs, and see if there are any errors or other strange behavior.

Comment: in the first instance, without the issue of paging works well. The list of job offers per company.

In the second rule, which would function like the first example (but without paging) can not catch the company ID, then not show any information. Empty page.

Does not give any error.

Comment: Do your server access logs indicate which page it took you to?  Note that Apache has its own logs, separate from PHP.  The only thing that would be displayed on the page are PHP errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo. `$4` doesn't exist in your example rule for pagination. Also if this is in `.htaccess`, the initial slash shouldn't be there. `.*` is greedy, so I've replaced it with any character, not a `/`.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?pag=$1&id=$3&page=$5 [NC,L]
```

`company/university-of-gloucestershire/1656/page/2` would become:

```
index.php?pag=company&id=1656&page=2
```

That rule needs to precede this one because you still have to catch the pages where someone's not specifying a page number:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)(/page/?)?$ index.php?pag=$1&id=$3&page=1 [NC,L]
```

`company/university-of-gloucestershire/1656/` and

`company/university-of-gloucestershire/1656/page` would become:

```
index.php?pag=company&id=1656&page=1
```

Comment: @RuiCosta Did you test them?